# Php change unordered variable character

Tags: php, strpos

I want to change a specific character. But the order isn't exact and not only the first one.
Here is the variable examples:

- 123_456_789.jpg
- 3210_5325_aa.jpg
- 54321-0888_555_1111.jpg

There are 1000 variables like this. I just want to change all **second** "_" characters. The result must be like this:

- 123_456**x**789.jpg
- 3210_5325**x**aa.jpg
- 54321-0888_555**x**1111.jpg

I've tried `substr` and `str_replace` but I couldn't understand how to do.
Can someone please show me a way to achieve this :)

Comment: have you tried using regular expressions?

Comment: I'm not pretty expert on php. I made lots of searches but couldn't understand how to adapt the regex for my issue.

Comment: You don't need to be a PHP expert to use regular expressions, they are a separate technology which is available to be used in most programming languages. They do take a bit of time to learn how to use them effectively though. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the details :) I had a tought that regex comes from php :) Can you please send me a tutorial link to understand regex better?

Comment: You can type "regex tutorial" into Google and find dozens, and then choose one which suits you (rather than me)

Comment: Sure, this is the best way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second one is always the last one, you can use `strrpos`.

```
<?php

$vals = [
    '123_456_789.jpg',
    '3210_5325_aa.jpg',
    '54321-0888_555_1111.jpg'
];

foreach ($vals as $val) {
    $pos = strrpos($val, '_');
    echo substr($val, 0, $pos) . 'x' . substr($val, $pos + 1) . '<BR>';
}

// 123_456x789.jpg
// 3210_5325xaa.jpg
// 54321-0888_555x1111.jpg
```

If it should be really the second one occurence (independently of real number of occurences), it could be:

```
<?php

$vals = [
    '123_456_789.jpg',
    '3210_5325_aa.jpg',
    '54321-0888_555_1111_32.jpg'
];

foreach ($vals as $val) {
    $pos = strpos($val, '_'); // 1st '_'
    $pos2 = strpos($val, '_', $pos + 1); // 2nd '_'
    echo substr($val, 0, $pos2) . 'x' . substr($val, $pos2 + 1) . '<BR>';
}

// 123_456x789.jpg
// 3210_5325xaa.jpg
// 54321-0888_555x1111_32.jpg
```

The second variant is regex, of course. I've showed you `strpos/strrpos` variants due to the question.

Comment: "all second "_" characters". In your case you're lucky that you don't have 3 underscores.

Comment: @u_mulder From example it seems like second = last. It could be standardized format, we don't know where filenames are taken. But you're right, I've added solution with strpos for the real second underscore.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked very well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested search/replace operation:

```
$f=[
    '123_456_789.jpg',
    '3210_5325_aa.jpg',
    '54321-0888_555_1111.jpg',
    '____.___'
];

foreach($f as $s) {
$s[strpos($s,"_")+1+strpos(substr($s,strpos($s,"_")+1),"_")]="x";
echo $s.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
123_456x789.jpg
3210_5325xaa.jpg
54321-0888_555x1111.jpg
_x__.___
```

First, find the position of the first underscore:

```
strpos($s,"_")
```

Take a substring of the string from the next character

```
substr($s,strpos($s,"_")+1)
```

and find the position of the next underscore

```
strpos(substr($s,strpos($s,"_")+1),"_")
```

Add in the other values, and use the `[]` notation to edit the string.

[Teh Playground!](https://www.tehplayground.com/dnOcrhUMMKfbcrpd)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to match only the second underscore using a pattern and replace the match with `x`

```
^[^\s_]+_[^\s_]+\K_
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\s_]+_[^\s_]+` Match the first `_` and followed by optional chars other than `_`
- `\K_` Forget what is matched so far using `\K` and then match the `_` which

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ZlMs0/1)

Or a bit more specific pattern and assert ending with `.jpg`

```
^[^\s_]+_[^\s_]+\K_(?=\S*\.jpg$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LOjyhd/1)

```
$re = '/^[^\s_]+_[^\s_]+\K_/m';
$str = '123_456_789.jpg
3210_5325_aa.jpg
54321-0888_555_1111.jpg';

echo preg_replace($re, 'x', $str);
```

Output

```
123_456x789.jpg
3210_5325xaa.jpg
54321-0888_555x1111.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)